# Re-define ctrl-d in sublime when using emmet

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

When I install the Emmet package in Sublime Text, it changes the definition of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. I'd like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to have the default behavior, which is to delete the character in front of the cursor. What should I fill in under?

Below when I define my User key bindings for the Emmet package?

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "???" },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "right_delete" }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Emmet README](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/README.md#overriding-keyboard-shortcuts), the correct way of disableing shortcuts is

> If you’re unhappy with default keymap, you can disable individual keyboard shortcuts with disabled_keymap_actions preference of Emmet.sublime-settings file.

The key for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is "balance_outward". The settings should then look like this:

```
{"disabled_keymap_actions": "balance_outward"}
```

You can find all the keys for different commands by opening the `Default (<os>).sublime-keymap` beloning to Emmet and looking at `args: action`.

Answer (score -1):

The quick & Dirty workaround would be to remove the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> definition on the emmet default keybinding file.

I'm looking for a cleaner solution though.